# catch string from a specific point

Tags: javascript, regex, match, extract, regex-group

How can I catch the string right from the underscore?
I don't want the underscore to be part of the result.

The result should be: `this is a test`
instead of `_this is a test`.

I want to solve this with regex because I try to understand
different scenarios.

```js
var re = /(?:_)(.*)/g; 
var str = 'foo _this is a test';
var m;
m = re.exec(str)

document.write(m[0]);
```

Comment: Your regex is good. Just get second group after executing your regex.

Comment: Thx a lot. I am just not experienced enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't just take the group 1 value. You take all of the Regex value instead. The code should be:

```
document.write(m[1]); // m[1] for taking group 1
```

Comment: Thx. I need more experience.

Comment: You are welcome! Can you please also accept the answer if it's helpful? Thx